# I am trying to configure LDAP as JNDI Resource in Pivotal

Tags: spring-mvc, ldap, gson, spring-ldap

I get some data with ldap authentication. I can do this correctly with this code.

```
List<Employees> emps=new ArrayList<Employees>();
    String url = "ldap://xxx:389";
    String base = "dc=xxx,dc=xxx,dc=xx";
    String userDn = "username";
    String password = "pass";
    try {
        LdapContextSource ctxSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ctxSrc.setUrl(url);
        ctxSrc.setBase(base);
        ctxSrc.setUserDn(userDn);
        ctxSrc.setPassword(password);
        ctxSrc.afterPropertiesSet();
        LdapTemplate lt = new LdapTemplate(ctxSrc);

        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "Person"));
        List<String> list = lt.search("", filter.encode(), new ContactAttributeMapperJSON());
        emps = new Gson().fromJson(list.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Employees>>() {
        }.getType());
```

this code works correctly. But i want hide my username and pass. So i get datas from content.xml(Pivotal).This is my content.xml:

```
<Resource name="ldap/LdapResource" auth="Container"
    type="javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext"
    factory="xxx"
    singleton="false" 
    java.naming.factory.initial="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
    java.naming.provider.url="ldap://xx:389"
    java.naming.security.authentication="simple"
    java.naming.security.principal="username"
    java.naming.security.credentials="pass." />
```

And my new code block :

```
        List<Employees> emps = new ArrayList<Employees>();
    try {
        Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
        LdapContext ldapContext = (LdapContext) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/ldap/LdapResource");
        *LdapTemplate lt = new LdapTemplate(ldapContext);*

        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("objectclass", "Person"));
        List<String> list = lt.search("", filter.encode(), new ContactAttributeMapperJSON());

        emps = new Gson().fromJson(list.toString(), new TypeToken<List<Employees>>() {
        }.getType());
```

here is my problem. I cant LdapTemplate with LdapContext. It works only LdapContextSource and I cant cast LdapContext to LdapContextSource. What should i do ?

Sorry for my bad English. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've done in that exact same situation is to create a `java.naming.spi.ObjectFactory` subclass that returns an `LdapContextSource` instance using the properties given in the `Resource` element. You can use the standard LDAP JNDI attributes from 'java.naming.Context' or use your own.

Only thing I still have to work out is how to deal with `java.naming.security.authentication` and `java.naming.security.protocol`.